# Proof verification : Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

**PROOF VERIFICATION**

> Show that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.

We define
$$A:=\{ω \in Ω:X_n(ω) \to X(ω) \text{ as } n \to \infty\}.$$
By almost sure convergence, we have $P(A)=1$. Also define
$$A_n(ε):=\{ω \in Ω:|X_n(ω)-X(ω)|<ε\}.$$
Convergence in probability is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(A_n(ε))=1$ for every $ε > 0$, which is what we want to show. Now, $ω \in A \implies \omega \in A_n(ε)$ for sufficiently large $n$ $[\geq N=N(ε)]$. Hence, $P(A) \leq P(A_n)$ for $n \geq N=N(ε)$. Thus,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n(ε)) \geq P(A)=1.$$

> This gives the result since $ε>0$ is arbitrarily chosen. What is bothering me is that the proof seems surprisingly simple. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is completely invalid: $\omega \in A$ implies $\omega \in A_n(\epsilon )$ for $n > N(\epsilon , \omega)$. $N(\epsilon , \omega)$ can depend on  $\omega $ which makes the argument wrong. Here is a correct proof: $0=P\{\limsup \{|X_n-X| >\epsilon \}\geq \limsup P\{|X_n-X| >\epsilon \}$ which proves convergence in probability.

Comment: Since we're taking $n \to \infty$, does dependence on $\omega$ matter? What I'm trying to argue is that $P(A) \leq P(A_n(ε))$ for $n \geq N=N(ε,\omega)$. Then it holds that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n(ε)) \geq P(A)$. Also, I'm interested in the Fatou-type inequality that you wrote. How do you prove that?

Comment: The inequality $P(A) \leq P(A_n(\epsilon ))$ may not hold for any particular  value of $n$ so your argument cannot be easily corrected. Second point: if you know Fatou's Lemma just apply it to indicator functions to get $P(\liminf A_n) \leq \liminf P(A_n)$. Now change $A_n$ to $A_n^{c}$ to get $P(\limsup A_n) \geq \limsup P(A_n)$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I understand now.